# AWS EKS CPU Utilization: What the meaning of Sum?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I use AWS Container Insights to monitor AWS EKS CPU Utilization. In the CloudWatch it shows values of Min, Max, Average and Sum. As an example below:

```
Min:      2.3664
Max:      5.5556
Average:  4.682
Sum:      397.97
```

I understand values of Min, Max and Average represent the percentage of CPU usages. But, what the meaning of Sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values submitted for the matching metric added together. This statistic can be useful for determining the total volume of a metric.

In this metric's case, it may not add any value.